# what is the meaning of communion in the paragraph？

Tags: figurative-language

> “Sometimes a meal is just a meal, and eating with others is simply eating with others. More often than not, though, it’s not. Once or twice a semester at least, I will stop discussion of the story or play under consideration to intone (and I invariably intone in bold): **whenever people eat or drink together, it’s communion**.For some reasons, this is often met with a slightly scandalized look,communion having for many readers **one and only one meaning**. While that meaning is very important, it is not the only one. Nor, for that matter, does
>   Christianity have a lock on the practice. Nearly every religion has some liturgical or social ritual involving the coming together of the faithful to share sustenance. ”

The paragraph is from *How to read literature like a professor*.
I just don't know what the true  meaning of communion in this sentence:communion having for many readers  one and only one meaning.
Here, “the only one meaning”,I wonder whether it refers to “a ceremony in christian  church ” or “the state of  sharing thoughts and feelings”.

Comment: To those voting to close:  The word "communion" has a number of meanings, but this writer is combining these to make a personal observation which may not be readily apparent from a dictionary definition.  There's a lot of nuance to the sentence which a non-native speaker might miss.

Answer (score 1):

The paragraph in question plays on at least two and perhaps three different meanings of the word "communion." The author does not intend the reader to understand the word in a single sense throughout the paragraph. He starts by giving **his** definition, namely "communion" = "whenever people eat or drink together." Although the author does not say so, he is deliberately conflating "communion" and "commensal event."

That is not a standard definition, but people are not prohibited from stipulating a definition. The OP gives two of the standard definitions in "sharing of thoughts and feelings" and "a ceremony in the Christian church." From the single quoted paragraph, it is impossible to be sure of the author's complete thought, but it seems to be  that a commensal event frequently may, or perhaps invariably does, lead to some degree of sharing of thoughts and feelings and that a commensal event can symbolize sharing of thoughts and feelings.

The author then alludes to another standard meaning, namely the Christian ceremony of Holy Communion, which many people do abbreviate as "communion." The author then implies that many people believe that Christian abbreviation to be the only meaning of "communion," but asserts that such a belief is incorrect. It is indeed incorrect: the dictionary gives at least three definitions of "communion." (Of course, none of the dictionary meanings is the author's own definition.) Moreover, as the author points out, other religions have commensal events intended to evoke a sharing of thoughts and feelings.

The paragraph is an attempt to link eating and drinking together with a general type of religious ceremony and the very broad meaning a sharing of feeling and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The writer argues that while the term "communion" has "one and only one meaning" to certain people -- related to the Catholic Eucharist -- the word itself has other, non-religious meanings, and should be perfectly acceptable to use for any kind of social gathering.

Furthermore Christianity is not the only religion that practices a form of ceremonial "communion", so even if we only consider the religious aspects of "communion", there's no reason to limit it to only Christian beliefs.

I expect that the writer will go on to explain more what he considers to be the "true" definition of *communion* and why he feels it is important.

Answer (score -2):

The *one and only one meaning* is the *Holy Communion* or *Eucharist*, a Christian religious ritual whereby people drink wine (symbolizing Jesus' blood) and eat bread (symbolizing Jesus' body).

The passage is trying to say that *communion* is not selective to Christianity; other religions have some ritual that is the same (sharing *sustenance*, or celebrating life).

Comment: This answer is utterly wrong as written. The word "communion" simply means "sharing, particularly of feelings" (see Merriam Webster or Harper Collins). It is true that "Holy Communion" has a special meaning in the Christian church and that "Holy Communion" is often abbreviated as "communion." But the phrase "communion with nature" is not Christian, indeed, it is anti-Christian to the extent that it is pantheistic. I believe, however, that the answer could be edited to explain that it is merely elucidating a mis-conception. "Quotation marks have a purpose.

Comment: @JeffMorrow What? The OP is asking for what the meaning of communion is in the phrase _communion having for many readers one and only one meaning_. I answered the question. I don't know what part of my answer you saw that says that _communion_ only refers to the Christian ritual...

Comment: "The one and only meaning [of "communion"] is the Holy Communion or Eucharist..." says quite clearly that "communion" has a meaning only as a sacrament of the Chritian church. That is false. I strongly suspect that you do not mean what you in fact wrote, but your answer needs to be edited.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Did you not read my response? _One and only one meaning_ are the **exact** words used, and that meaning of communion is what it refers to.

Comment: If you meant to quote rather than assert, use quotation marks. Moreover, the phrase quoted is not intended to be construed as correct. Irony is a thing. You persist in refusing to edit what is clearly wrong.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Editing is unnecessary if people take the time to understand the basis of an answer rather than leaping quickly to judgement.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Not only that, but the question is (in quotation marks): "I just don't know what the true meaning of communion in this sentence:communion having for many readers one and only one meaning."

Comment: Perhaps a site meant for learners should try to be correct and non-inferential. My original post asked for some edits so that the literal meaning of the answer being commented on would not be fallacious. Why is that so hard for you to do? Do you truly believe that the sole meaning of communion is a Christian ritual? That is what you said, and it is wrong.

Comment: @JeffMorrow It's not hard for me to do anything. I'm trying to have a discussion. Not only do I not believe it is the only meaning, you know that I don't as well, so I don't understand what we're still talking about if you both know what I meant and know my style of writing answers.